# Как определить Activity?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Есть два Activity. В обоих RecyclerView с CardView.
Хочу использовать для них один и тот же ViewHolder+Adapter. 
Конечно,  Item в CardView немного разные для первого и второго Activity. Поэтому ViewHolder+Adapter должны работать по-разному в зависимости от того  для которого Activity они применены.

```
public class RemindListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RemindListAdapter.RemindViewHolder> {
    private List<RemindDTO> data;

    public RemindListAdapter(List<RemindDTO> data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    @Override
    public RemindViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.remind_item, parent, false);
        return new RemindViewHolder(view);
    }


 @Override
 public void onBindViewHolder(RemindViewHolder holder, int position) {
        final String itemString = data.get(position).getTitle();
     holder.title.setText(itemString);
     holder.cardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         @Override
         public void onClick(View view) {
             Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(),SongActivity.class);
             intent.putExtra("name", itemString);
             view.getContext().startActivity(intent);
         }
     });

 }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    public static class RemindViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        CardView cardView;
        TextView title;
        TextView year;

        public RemindViewHolder (View itemView){
            super(itemView);
            cardView=(CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cardView);
            Context context = itemView.getContext();

            if (context.equals(MainActivity.class)){
                title=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.title);
                year=(TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.year);
            }


        }
    }
}
```

Есть идея сделать проверку так:

```
public RemindViewHolder (View itemView){
        super(itemView);
        cardView=(CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cardView);
        Context context = itemView.getContext();

        if (context.equals(MainActivity.class)){
            title=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.title);
            year=(TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.year);
        }


    }
```

Но не понятно, разные ли Context'ы у двух Activity из одного приложения. И применим ли для такой задачи метод equals.
Как Adapter'у и Holder'у определить в каком Activity они работают?

Comment: Попробуйте передать ссылку на вашу Activty в конструктор RemindListAdapter, а следом в конструктор RemindViewHolder. А вообще вроде View.getContext() должен возвращать текущее Activity

Comment: Да.Хорошая идея передать идентификатор в конструкторе. Реализовал. Понял, что моя изначальная задумка заставляет  делать слишком много проверок. Поэтому класс ViewHolder+Adapter получается слишком ненадёжным. Фактически я получил раздутый класс, с множеством тонких мест. А взамен лишь универсальность и удобство вызова. Ну и "красивость" кода. В итоге, сделал каждому Recycrel View свой ViewHolder+Adapter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно сделать универсальный адаптер, который сможет работать с любыми холдерами и моделями. В вашем случае он будет работать с один холдером и 2 моделями.

Для этого нужно:

- делигировать создание холдеров и их биндинг прослойке между адаптером
  и холдером с моделью. Я называю этот клас `ViewRendererЧто-тотам`. Для каждого типа модели(итема) пишется свой рендерер, который наследуется от общего интерфейса `ViewRenderer`. Все методы в адаптере дергаются через этот интерфейс.
- наследовать все модели от одного интерфейса,который минимально должен
  содержать метод `getType()` - он вызывается в адаптере для
  определения типа рендерера, с которым необходимо работать для данной модели.
- для каждой модели и холдера реализовывать свой `ViewRenderer` в
  котором будет создаваться холдер и биндится с моделью.

Таким образом можно использовать один адаптер с обсолютно любыми моделями и холдерами.

Понятно что такой подход немного избыточен в вашем случае, т.к. проще написать 2 адаптера, чем делать адаптер и 2 прослойки (ViewRender) для каждой модели. Но если в вашем приложении будет хотя бы 3-4 модели для RecyclerView - этот подход неплохо сократит код.

Подробное описание на русском и примеры с кодом очень хорошо описаны хорошим человеком на известом форуме)
Если интересно прочтите [это](https://habr.com/post/323862/), затем [это](https://habr.com/post/345954/)

Comment: Спасибо.Интересный подход. Действительно, для меня это избыточно.